# How to see a list of repositories added to Ubuntu?

Tags: repository, command-line

I want to see a list of repositories so that I have added to Ubuntu.
How can I acquire such a list? Is there a command I can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two different places in Debian for source list files:
Most of the default source listings are in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

While a few packages may add their own smaller lists to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

To view each of them, you can cat them individually. (like `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, or `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`)

This is quite a familiar style in debian packaging. For instance apache keeps its common configuration in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, while several other packages (like phpmyadmin) may add their own smaller configurations in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`

Answer (score 5):

All the repositories are listed in the `.list` files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

Comment: Thank you! but i want to see them in terminal!
which command show them?

Comment: cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && cat *.list

Answer (score 1):

This command will list them quite clearly and nicely:

```
for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done
```

([Here's an example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1068060/) of what the output can look like.)

You may also want to list the repositories configured in the master configuration file:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: "*The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist.*" :(

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -EvRH ^"$|\#" /etc/apt/source*
```

Comment: I have added some extra formatting to your answer to enhance readability; could you expand a little on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```bash
grep -Rh ^deb /etc/apt/sources.li* | sort -u
```

1. `grep -Rh ^deb /etc/apt/sources.li*` prints every line starting with the word "deb" in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and every file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. The `R` is for "recursive" and the `h` suppresses the filenames because I don't want to see them.
2. `sort -u` sorts the input and removes duplicates. I put it in there because `/etc/apt/sources.list.save` exists on my system. I could probably delete it but it ain't hurtin' nuthin'.